# Как найти и убрать вредноносный код Yii2

Tags: php, css, yii2

На класс adverts применяются стили см. скриншот, как найти их и убрать?
Поиск в проекте ничего не находит.

[image: Стили которые прячут ссылки]

```
a[href^="http://www.roboform.com/php/land.php"], a[href^="http://www.seekbang.com/cs/"], a[href^="http://www.sex.com/?utm_"], a[href^="http://www.sexgangsters.com/?pid="], a[href^="http://www.sfippa.com/"], a[href^="http://www.streamate.com/exports/"], a[href^="http://www.streamtunerhd.com/signup?"], a[href^="http://www.terraclicks.com/"], a[href^="http://www.text-link-ads.com/"], a[href^="http://www.tirerack.com/affiliates/"], a[href^="http://www.torntv-downloader.com/"], a[href^="http://www.torntvdl.com/"], a[href^="http://www.twinplan.com/AF_"], a[href^="http://www.uniblue.com/cm/"], a[href^="http://www.urmediazone.com/signup"], a[href^="http://www.usearchmedia.com/signup?"], a[href^="http://www.wantstraffic.com/"], a[href^="http://www.webtrackerplus.com/"], a[href^="http://www1.clickdownloader.com/"], a[href^="http://wxdownloadmanager.com/dl/"], a[href^="http://xads.zedo.com/"], a[href^="http://yads.zedo.com/"], a[href^="http://z1.zedo.com/"], a[href^="http://zevera.com/afi.html"], a[href^="https://affiliates.bet-at-home.com/processing/"], a[href^="https://atomidownload.com/"], a[href^="https://bs.serving-sys.com"], a[href^="https://dediseedbox.com/clients/aff.php?"], a[href^="https://dltags.com/"], a[href^="https://friendlyduck.com/AF_"], a[href^="https://secure.eveonline.com/ft/?aid="], a[href^="https://www.FriendlyDuck.com/AF_"], a[href^="https://www.firstload.com/affiliate/"], a[href^="https://www.friendlyduck.com/AF_"], a[href^="https://www.oboom.com/ad/"], a[href^="https://www.secureupload.eu/suprerefid="], a[href^="https://www.share-online.biz/affiliate/"], a[onmousedown^="this.href='http://staffpicks.outbrain.com/network/redir?"][target="_blank"], a[onmousedown^="this.href='http://staffpicks.outbrain.com/network/redir?"][target="_blank"] + .ob_source, a[onmousedown^="this.href='https://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?"][target="_blank"] + .ob_source, a[style="display:block;width:300px;min-height:250px"][href^="http://li.cnet.com/click?"], aside[id^="div-gpt-ad"], div[id^="ADV-SLOT-"], div[id^="YFBMSN"], div[id^="adrotate_widgets-"], div[id^="cns_ads_"], div[id^="dfp-slot-"], div[id^="div-adtech-ad-"], div[id^="div_ad_stack_"], div[id^="div_openx_ad_"], div[id^="dmRosAdWrapper"], div[id^="google_dfp_"], div[id^="proadszone-"], div[itemtype="http://www.schema.org/WPAdBlock"], iframe[src^="http://cdn1.adexprt.com/"], iframe[src^="http://cdn2.adexprt.com/"], img[alt^="Fuckbook"], input[onclick^="window.open('http://www.FriendlyDuck.com/AF_"], input[onclick^="window.open('http://www.friendlyduck.com/AF_"], p[id^="div-gpt-ad-"], script[src^="http://free-shoutbox.net/app/webroot/shoutbox/sb.php?shoutbox="] + #freeshoutbox_content, #mobile-swipe-banner, .gbfwa > div[class$="_item"], iframe[src^="http://static.mozo.com.au/strips/"], .brandpost_inarticle, #rhs_whistleout_widget, #wo-widget-wrap, #assetsListings[style="display: block;"], #magnify_widget_playlist_item_companion, #flowplayer > div[style="position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 275px; left: 222.5px; top: 85px; z-index: 999;"], #flowplayer > div[style="z-index: 208; position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 275px; left: 222.5px; top: 85px;"], .Mpopup + #Mad > #MadZone, .l-container > #fishtank, #center_col > #_Emc, #center_col > #main > .dfrd > .mnr-c > .c._oc._zs, #center_col > #res > #topstuff + #search > div > #ires > #rso > #flun, #center_col > #resultStats + #tads, #center_col > #resultStats + #tads + #res + #tads, #center_col > #resultStats + div + #res + #tads, #center_col > #resultStats + div[style="border:1px solid #dedede;margin-bottom:11px;padding:5px 7px 5px 6px"], #center_col > #taw > #tvcap > .rscontainer, #center_col > div[style="font-size:14px;margin-right:0;min-height:5px"] > div[style="font-size:14px;margin:0 4px;padding:1px 5px;background:#fff8e7"], #cnt #center_col > #res > #topstuff > .ts, #cnt #center_col > #taw > #tvcap > .c._oc._Lp, #main_col > #center_col div[style="font-size:14px;margin:0 4px;padding:1px 5px;background:#fff7ed"], #mbEnd[cellspacing="0"][cellpadding="0"], #mclip_container:last-child, #mn #center_col > div > h2.spon:first-child, #mn #center_col > div > h2.spon:first-child + ol:last-child, #mn div[style="position:relative"] > #center_col > ._Ak, #mn div[style="position:relative"] > #center_col > div > ._dPg, #resultspanel > #topads, #rhs_block .mod > .gws-local-hotels__booking-module, #rhs_block .mod > .luhb-div > div[data-async-type="updateHotelBookingModule"], #rhs_block > #mbEnd, #rhs_block > .ts[cellspacing="0"][cellpadding="0"][style="padding:0"], #rhs_block > ol > .rhsvw > .kp-blk > .xpdopen > ._OKe > ol > ._DJe > .luhb-div, #rhs_block > script + .c._oc._Ve.rhsvw, #rhswrapper > #rhssection[border="0"][bgcolor="#ffffff"], #ssmiwdiv[jsdisplay], #tads + div + .c, #tads.c, #tadsb.c, #tadsto.c, #topstuff > #tads, .GB3L-QEDGY .GB3L-QEDF- > .GB3L-QEDE-, .GFYY1SVD2 > .GFYY1SVC2 > .GFYY1SVF5, .GFYY1SVE2 > .GFYY1SVD2 > .GFYY1SVG5, .GHOFUQ5BG2 > .GHOFUQ5BF2 > .GHOFUQ5BG5, .GJJKPX2N1 > .GJJKPX2M1 > .GJJKPX2P4, .GKJYXHBF2 > .GKJYXHBE2 > .GKJYXHBH5, .GPMV2XEDA2 > .GPMV2XEDP1 > .GPMV2XEDJBB, .ch[onclick="ga(this,event)"], .commercial-unit-desktop-rhs, .commercial-unit-desktop-top, .commercial-unit-mobile-top, .lads[width="100%"][style="background:#FFF8DD"], .mod > ._jH + .rscontainer, .mw > #rcnt > #center_col > #taw > #tvcap > .c, .mw > #rcnt > #center_col > #taw > .c, .ra[align="left"][width="30%"], .ra[align="right"][width="30%"], .ra[width="30%"][align="right"] + table[width="70%"][cellpadding="0"], .rhsvw[style="background-color:#fff;margin:0 0 14px;padding-bottom:1px;padding-top:1px;"], .rscontainer > .ellip, .widget-pane-section-result[data-result-ad-type], #ads > .dose > .dosesingle, #content > #center > .dose > .dosesingle, #content > #right > .dose > .dosesingle, #header + #content > #left > #rlblock_left, .trc_rbox_div a[target="_blank"][href^="http://tab"], #MAIN.ShowTopic > .ad, div[id^="mainads"], .__y_elastic .__y_item, .__y_inner > .__y_item, .__y_outer, .__yinit .__y_item, .__ywl .__y_item, .__ywvr .__y_item, .__zinit .__y_item, .icons-rss-feed + .icons-rss-feed div[class$="_item"], .inlineNewsletterSubscription + .inlineNewsletterSubscription div[class$="_item"], .jobs-information-call-to-action + .jobs-information-call-to-action div[class$="_item"], .component-zergnet, .content-zergnet, .js-footer-zerg, .td-zergnet, .zergnet-holder, .zergnet-row, .abp_ob_exist, #AD_Top, #AD_banner, #AdBar, #AdColumn, #AdContainer, #AdHeader, #AdImage, #AdSense1, #AdSense2, #Adcode, #AdvertiseFrame, #Advertisements, #BannerAd, #BottomAdContainer, #BottomAds, #ContentAd, #GoogleRelatedAds, #LoungeAdsDiv, #PreRollAd, #RightAdBlock, #TopAd, #WNAd41, #ad-728, #ad-area, #ad-atf-mid, #ad-atf-top, #ad-background, #ad-banner, #ad-bg, #ad-bottom, #ad-btf-bot, #ad-container, #ad-frame, #ad-header, #ad-header-728x90, #ad-horizontal, #ad-leaderboard, #ad-main, #ad-panel, #ad-right, #ad-right-top, #ad-rotator, #ad-slot-1, #ad-slot-2, #ad-text, #ad-top, #ad-top-banner-placeholder, #ad-top-wrap, #ad-top-wrapper, #ad-unit, #ad-wrapper, #ad468, #ad728, #ad728x90, #adBanner, #adBelt, #adBottom, #adComponentWrapper, #adContent, #adDiv, #adFrame, #adGallery, #adHeader, #adHolder, #adLayer, #adLeader, #adPosition0, #adText, #adTop, #adUnit, #ad_1, #ad_2, #ad_3, #ad_4, #ad_5, #ad_728_90, #ad_area, #ad_banner, #ad_center, #ad_content, #ad_header, #ad_leaderboard, #ad_main, #ad_overlay, #ad_space, #ad_square, #ad_table, #ad_text:not(textarea), #ad_topslot, #ad_unit, #ad_website_top, #ad_wrap, #ad_wrapper, #ad_zone1, #adaptv_ad_player_div, #adbackground, #adbanner, #adbar, #adblock, #adblock1, #adblock2, #adboard, #adbody, #adbox, #adcode, #adcontainer, #adcontainer1, #adcontainer2, #adcontainer3, #adcontent, #adhead, #adheader, #adimg1, #adl_300x250, #adlayer, #adnews, #adposition3, #adright, #adrotate_widgets-3, #ads-col, #ads-wrapper, #ads1, #adsHeader, #ads_bottom, #ads_box, #ads_left, #ads_postdownload, #ads_right, #ads_section_textlinks, #ads_top, #ads_wrapper, #adsdiv, #adsense, #adsense_block, #adsense_inline, #adsensewide, #adspace, #adspace_top, #adspot-300x250-pos-1, #adspot-300x250-pos-2, #adstop, #adswidget1-quick-adsense, #adtext, #adtop, #adunit, #adv-masthead, #adv-top, #adver2, #adver5, #advert-placeholder-post-content-image-1, #advert1, #advert2, #advertContainer, #advert_box, #advertise, #advertisement1, #advertiserReports, #advertisetop, #advertising_wrapper, #advertorial, #adverts, #advtop, #adwrapper, #adzerk_by, #article-ad, #article-footer-sponsors, #babAdTop, #banner-ad, #bannerAd, #bannerAdWrapper, #banner_topad, #bannerad, #bbccom_mpu, #bigAd, #bigad, #body_ad, #bottom-ad, #bottom-ads-container, #bottomAd, #bottomAds, #bottom_ad, #bottomad, #bsap_aplink, #btmsponsoredcontent, #buysellads, #center-ad, #centerads, #cmn_ad_tag_head, #companionAd, #content-header-ad, #contentAd, #content_ads, #content_adv, #contentad, #contentad-story-bottom-1, #contentad-top-adsense-1, #dart-container-728x90, #dfp_ad_Entry_728x90, #dfp_ad_Home_728x90, #divAd, #div_prerollAd_1, #download_ad, #extraAdsBlock, #featuread, #featured-ads, #featuredAds, #footer-ads, #footer_ad, #footer_ads, #frnAdSky, #gAds, #game-ad, #google-adsense, #googleAd, #google_ads, #googlead, #googleadsense, #gpt2_ads_widget-6, #gridAdSidebar, #halfPageAd, #head-ad, #header-ad, #header-ads, #headerAd, #headerAdContainer, #header_ad, #header_ads, #homead, #iqadtile1, #iqadtile4, #iqadtile9, #ka_adRightSkyscraperWide, #leaderAd, #leaderBoardAd, #leaderboard-ad, #leaderboard-advertisement, #leaderboardad, #left-ad, #left_ads, #leftad, #leftads, #liste_top_ads_wrapper, #logoAd, #logo_ad, #mainAd, #main_ad, #mpu2, #mpu2_container, #mpu_container, #msad, #myAd, #narrow_ad_unit, #p-googleadsense, #player_ads, #pre_advertising_wrapper, #prerollAd, #promo-ad, #publicidad, #reklama, #rh-ad, #rightAd300x250, #rightAd300x250Lower, #rightAds, #right_ads, #right_adsense, #search-sponsor, #searchAd, #search_ads, #sideAd, #side_ads, #sidebar-ads, #sidebar_ad, #sidebar_ads, #single-ad, #skybox-ad, #sponsorAdDiv, #sponsorText, #sponsored-links, #sponsored_link, #sponsored_link_bottom, #sponsored_links, #sponsoredwellcontainerbottom, #sponsors-home, #taboola-content, #takeover_ad, #td-applet-ads_container, #theAd, #top-ad, #top-ad-content, #top-banner-ad, #topAd, #topAd728x90, #topAdSpace, #topAdSpace_div, #topAdvert, #topBannerAd, #top_ad, #top_ads, #topad, #topadvert, #topbannerad, #under_story_ad, #videoAd, #videoads, #wide_ad_unit, #wide_ad_unit2, #wp_pro_ad_system_ad_zone, .ADBAR, .AD_area, .Ad-Container, .Ad-label, .AdBody:not(body), .AdBox, .AdInfo, .AdSense, .AdSidebar, .AdTitle, .Adsense, .AdvertContainer, .HomeAds, .IM_ad_unit, .LazyLoadAd, .LoungeAdsBottomLinks, .RelatedAds, .SidekickItem-Ads, .SponsoredContent, .SponsoredLinks, .SponsoredResults, .WP_Widget_Ad_manager, .ad-1, .ad-160-600, .ad-2, .ad-300-250, .ad-300x250, .ad-4, .ad-5, .ad-728-90, .ad-970, .ad-atf, .ad-background, .ad-banner, .ad-block, .ad-body, .ad-border, .ad-btn, .ad-button, .ad-cat, .ad-cell, .ad-center, .ad-container-300x250, .ad-content, .ad-desktop, .ad-disclaimer, .ad-display, .ad-enabled, .ad-force-center, .ad-google, .ad-head, .ad-header, .ad-holder, .ad-horizontal, .ad-icon, .ad-img, .ad-inner, .ad-inserter, .ad-item, .ad-label, .ad-leader-top, .ad-leaderboard, .ad-left, .ad-line, .ad-link, .ad-links, .ad-loaded, .ad-location, .ad-med-rect, .ad-medium-two, .ad-panel, .ad-placement, .ad-right, .ad-row, .ad-s-rendered, .ad-section, .ad-served, .ad-sidebar, .ad-sky, .ad-slot, .ad-source, .ad-space, .ad-square, .ad-stack, .ad-text, .ad-tl1, .ad-top, .ad-unit, .ad-unit-300-wrapper, .ad-unit-label, .ad-vertical-container, .ad-wide, .ad-widget, .ad-wrap, .ad-wrapper, .ad300, .ad300x250, .ad300x600, .ad468, .ad728, .ad728x90, .ad90, .adBlock, .adBottomBoard, .adBox, .adChoicesLogo, .adContent, .adDiv, .adElement, .adFrame, .adFrameCnt, .adHead, .adHeader, .adHeaderblack, .adHeadline, .adHolder, .adHoldert, .adImg, .adItem, .adLink, .adMessage, .adMiddle, .adMod, .adModule, .adOverlay, .adPanel, .adPod, .adResult, .adRight, .adRotator, .adSpace, .adSpot, .adText, .adTitle, .adTopHome, .adWidget, .adWrap, .ad_1, .ad_160, .ad_160x600, .ad_2, .ad_3, .ad_728x90, .ad_960, .ad_Right, .ad_adInfo, .ad_block, .ad_body, .ad_bottom, .ad_box, .ad_boxright1, .ad_container, .ad_default, .ad_description, .ad_footer, .ad_global_header, .ad_halfpage, .ad_head_rectangle, .ad_header, .ad_img, .ad_item, .ad_leaderboard, .ad_leaderboard_atf, .ad_middle, .ad_note, .ad_outer, .ad_placement, .ad_promo, .ad_slug_table, .ad_space, .ad_spot, .ad_text, .ad_title, .ad_trick_header, .ad_trick_left, .ad_unit, .ad_wrap, .ad_wrapper, .adarea, .adbanner, .adbar, .adbottom, .adbutton, .adcode, .adcolumn, .adcont, .addiv, .adframe, .adfree, .adheader, .adholder, .adinfo, .adinjwidget, .adkit, .adlink, .adlist, .admain, .admiddle, .adplace, .adright, .adrow1, .adrow2, .ads-1, .ads-2, .ads-3, .ads-area, .ads-bg, .ads-col, .ads-header, .ads-holder, .ads-inline, .ads-item, .ads-label, .ads-post, .ads-right, .ads-section, .ads-title, .ads-top, .ads1, .ads160-600, .ads160_600-widget, .adsBlock, .adsWidget, .ads_300, .ads_ad_box, .ads_ad_box2, .ads_by, .ads_catDiv, .ads_div, .ads_google, .ads_header, .ads_top, .ads_wrapper, .adsbottombox, .adsbox, .adsbygoogle, .adscontainer, .adsense_single, .adshome, .adside, .adslot, .adslot_1, .adslot_blurred, .adspace, .adspace-widget, .adspot, .adtable, .adtile, .adtop, .adunit, .adunit-middle, .adv-border, .adv-slide-block-wrapper, .adv300, .adv_300, .advads_widget, .advert-block, .advert-box, .advert-container, .advert-content, .advert-horizontal, .advert-wrapper, .advert2, .advertColumn, .advertCont, .advertContainer, .advertLink, .advertText, .advert_area, .advert_container, .advert_list, .advertbox, .advertisement-1, .advertisement-block, .advertisement-swimlane, .advertisement-text, .advertiser, .advertising_banner, .advertising_block, .advertisment, .advertorial, .adverts, .adverttext, .adwords, .adwrap-widget, .afs_ads, .after-post-ad, .article_ad, .atf-ad-medRect, .b-advert, .banner-ad, .banner-ads, .banner160x600, .banner300, .bannerAd, .banner_728x90, .banner_ad, .bannerad, .bbccom_advert, .bean-advertisment, .block-ad, .block-simpleads, .blog-ads, .bomAd, .bottom-ad, .bottom-ad-container, .bottom-ads, .bottom-left-ad, .bottomAds, .bottom_ad, .bottom_ad_block, .bottom_ads, .bottomad, .box-ad, .box-ads, .box-radvert, .box-recommend-ad, .boxad, .boxadv, .bsa_it_ad, .btn-ad, .bullet-sponsored-links-gray, .bxad, .can_ad_slug, .category-ad, .change_AdContainer, .chitikaAdBlock, .cmAd, .container_ad, .container_row_ad, .contentAd, .contentAds, .content_ads, .content_tagsAdTech, .cp-adsInited, .csiAd_medium, .custom-ad, .desktop-ad, .desktop_ad, .dfp-tag-wrapper, .displayAd, .div_adv300, .download_ad, .ezAdsense, .featured-ad, .featured-ads, .featuredAdBox, .flash-advertisement, .footer-ad, .footer-ad-elevated, .footer-ads, .footer-leaderboard-ad, .footerad, .for-taboola, .forumAd, .frn_adbox, .frn_placeholder_google_ads, .gallery-ad, .gemini-ad, .google-ad, .google-sponsored, .googleAdSense, .googleAds, .googleAdsense, .googleInsideAd, .google_ad, .google_ads, .google_ads_v3, .greyAd, .has-ad, .header-ad, .header-ad-wrapper, .headerAd, .header_ad, .header_ad_center, .header_advert, .headerad, .headerads, .home-ad, .home-ads, .homeAd, .homead, .homepage-ad, .homepage_ads, .horizontalAdText, .horizontal_ad, .ht_ad_widget, .img_ad, .imgad, .inlinead, .inner_ad, .innerad, .internal_ad, .interstitial_ad_wrapper, .ipsAd, .iqadlinebottom, .is-sponsored, .item-ads, .item-container-ad, .js-native-ad, .js-stream-ad, .js-stream-featured-ad, .lbc-ad, .leaderboard-ad, .leaderboard-ads, .leftAd, .leftad, .ligatus, .list-ad, .list-ads, .listad, .logo-ad, .lx_ad_title, .marketing-ad, .mediumRectangleAd, .member-ads, .mid_ad, .middle_AD, .mod-adopenx, .module-ad, .mom-ad, .mpu-ad, .native-ad, .newsAd, .newsad, .node-ad, .oasad, .ob_ads_header, .ob_container .item-container-obpd, .ob_container a[data-redirect^="http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?"], .ob_dual_right > .ob_ads_header ~ .odb_div, .oio-banner-zone, .openx, .page-ad, .page_ad, .pagefair-acceptable, .pfAd, .plainAd, .playerAd, .player_ad, .player_hover_ad, .pm-ad, .pm-ad-zone, .post-ad, .post-sponsored, .post_ad, .postad, .premiumAdOverlay, .premiumAdOverlayClose, .profile-ad-container, .promoAd, .pub_300x250, .pub_300x250m, .pub_728x90, .pushdown-ad, .rail-ad, .rbRectAd, .rectangle_ad, .refreshAds, .region-top-ad-position, .reklam, .reklama, .reklama1, .reportAdLink, .resultad, .review-ad, .right-ad, .rightAd, .right_ad, .right_ads_column, .rightad, .rightads, .rightadv, .rmx-ad, .s_ad_160x600, .s_ad_300x250, .sb-ad-margin, .sb-top-sec-ad, .searchAds, .searchad, .searchads, .section-sponsor, .showAd, .side-ad, .side-bar-ad-position1, .sideAd, .sidebar-ad, .sidebar-ad-slot, .sidebar-ads, .sidebar-advertisement, .sidebar_ads, .single-ad, .singleAd, .skinAd, .sky_ad, .skyscraperAd, .slide-ad, .smallAd, .small_ad, .smallads, .sponsor-block, .sponsor-box, .sponsor-logo, .sponsor-text, .sponsorBlock, .sponsorBottom, .sponsored-inmail, .sponsored-inmail-legacy, .sponsored-links, .sponsoredLinks, .sponsorlink, .sponsors-box, .sponsorshipbox, .square-ad, .sr-in-feed-ads, .srp-grid-speed-ad3, .static-ad, .sticky-ad, .story-ad, .taboola-ad, .taboola-inbetweener, .taboola-left-rail-wrapper, .taboola-unit, .taboola_blk, .tc_ad_unit, .td-a-rec-id-custom_ad_1, .td-adspot-title, .text-ad, .text-ad-links, .text-ads, .textAd, .text_ad, .text_ads, .textad, .textads, .top-ad, .top-ad-container, .top-ad-content, .top-ad-wrapper, .topAds, .top_ad, .top_ad_div, .top_ad_wrap {
display: none;
visibility: hidden;
orphans: 4321;
```

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос так что б было ясно в чем проблема

Comment: Судя по тому, что видно на картинке - один из .js  скриптов генерит данный блок стилей. можете отключить все подгружаемые скрипты и по очереди подключать, проверяя когда появится сей кошмар.

Answer (score 1):

На хабре была отличная статья https://habrahabr.ru/post/188878/
и еще https://habrahabr.ru/post/141710/ и https://habrahabr.ru/post/139453/